# How to get fields of djangocms-blog post extension from Post object?

Tags: django-cms

I have a post extension loaded in my django/django-cms/djangocms-blog project, that adds a few fields.

How can I get those fields from a Post object?

Here's an example of post:

```py
$ python3 manage.py shell
>>> from djangocms_blog.models import Post
>>> post = Post.objects.first()
>>> post
<Post: Test post>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that there's an `extension` "reverse many to one" available in the `Post` object:

```py
>>> dir(post)  #                                 vvvvvvvvv I found this
['DoesNotExist', 'Meta', '[... truncated ...]', 'extension', '[... truncated ...]']
>>> post.extension
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.<locals>.RelatedManager object at 0xd34db33f>
>>> post.extension.first()
<PostExtension: PostExtension object (1)>
```

So I just need to call it directly using `post.extension.first()`:

```py
>>> post.extension.first().my_custom_field
1
```

I don't think my Posts will have multiple post_extensions in this project so I'll stick with `.first()`, but I think each app that adds a post_extension to the Posts will add another post_extension object to the object.

*Edit: I can add others instances of the same post extension field to the Post object, I didn't know that post extension worked this way. I don't know how to limit the number of post extension per Post, though.*

*Second edit:* I just found this function in the Django Admin Inline code:

```py
    def get_max_num(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """Hook for customizing the max number of extra inline forms."""
        return self.max_num
```

So I added my own function in my `PostExtensionInline(admin.TabularInline)` class:

```py
    def get_max_num(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        return 1
```